# ULTRA big problem. Ubuntu Gnome 16.10 driver isue

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gnome

I really need your help. I have an acer Aspire-E5-771G laptop with Nvidia Geforce 840m drivers. 
When I installed Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 everything worked perfectly. 
But when I updated them to 16.10 , after the necessary restart of my computer, Ubuntu wouldnt boot. I got a black screen. 
I think the problem is with nvidia card. But im pretty noob to these things. Can someone help me u??

Comment: sorry to hear about your trouble. Unfortunately, updating Ubuntu can cause problems. When you boot from the Ubuntu USB stick or DVD, does the computer work? If so, then the upgrade probably caused your problem. There is some good advice [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1946145). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass the login screen and login to a text-only console and uninstall the Nvidia driver from there.

1. Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to open a virtual console.
2. In the console you will be prompted to enter your username. Type your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. You will be prompted to enter your login password. Type your login password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Run these commands to uninstall the existing Nvidia driver and reboot.

   ```
    sudo apt-get remove nvidia-*    
    sudo reboot
   ```
5. You should be able to login normally when the system restarts and you will be able to get to your desktop environment.
6. After the computer reboots, open the terminal and run this command to identify the recommended proprietary graphics driver for your system.

   ```
    ubuntu-drivers devices
   ```

Install the proprietary graphics driver that has *[Recommended]* after it and reboot the computer.